# Getting java.io.IOException: Broken pipe exception when navigating in a video that is being streamed as a multi part file stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, video-streaming

I am playing around with a simple video streaming spring boot application using the `MultipartFileSender` class in [this](https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/d927d9b8cb9ea1268af74316cd20b7192ca92da7/src/main/java/lan/dk/podcastserver/utils/multipart/MultipartFileSender.java) github repository. Since it is a very big file I didn't want to include it here but if needed I can include it.

I have my controller as follows:

```
package org.murat.test.controllers;

import org.murat.test.Utils.MultipartFileSender;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class VideoController {
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "video", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getVideo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        File file = new File("/test-videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4");
        try {
            logger.debug("Streaming file '" + file.getName() + "'...");
            MultipartFileSender.fromFile(file)
                    .with(request)
                    .with(response)
                    .serveResource();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            logger.error(errorMessage, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything runs perfectly as I go to  the URL http://hostname:8080/video and I can play, pause, rewind and navigate in the video.

My only concern at this point is, every time I navigate around the video (even when I start it) I get the `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` exception.

I did a bit of research and found out that this happens if the user closes the website or their connection when the server is trying to serve something to the user. So in my case this happens because when I drag to another frame:

1. Video pauses.
2. Goes to the desired frame.
3. Video starts running from that
   frame.

I assume at this point the original connection is lost and another one is created.

My questions are:

1. Can I make the switch between the connections gracefully without getting this error?
2. If not, can I safely ignore this error (perhaps force it to
   display it as warning/debug when I catch this particular exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are not supporting byte-range requests.  Most, if not all, video players will expect this.  They may degrade gracefully to use regular (non-byte range) requests but I doubt the player will ever be fully-functional.

[Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) supports video streaming (byte-ranges) out of the box.  Using Spring Content FS (i.e. Spring Content for the file-system) you would be able to create yourself a Store backed by the filesystem, place your video(s) in that store, and using Spring Content REST serve them over HTTP.

Create a new Spring Boot project via start.spring.io or via your IDE spring project wizard (Spring Boot 1.5.10 at time of writing).  Add the following Spring Content dependencies so you end up with these:-

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Standard Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Content -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In your Spring Boot Application class, create a VideoStore. Annotate it as a Store REST resource.  This causes Spring Content to inject an implementation (of this interface) as well as REST endpoints saving you from having to write any this (i.e. the controller code shown above plus some):-

```
    @SpringBootApplication 
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {        
           SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);  
        }

        @StoreRestResource(path="test-videos")  
        public interface VideoStore extends Store<String> {} 
    }
```

By default Spring Content will create a store under java.io.tmpdir.  So you will also need to set the SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT environment variable to point to the root of your "store".

Copy your video into this "root" location.  Start the application and your video(s) will be streamable from:-

> /test-videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Let me know if you aren't using Spring Boot and I can post a non-spring boot example.

Comment: When I try to go to `http://hostname:8080/test-videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4`, I am getting a 404 error despite the fact that I added the relevant classes and `SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT` is set to `/test-videos/`. In the log I actually see `Defaulting filesystem root to /test-videos/`. However I also see a warning `Locations list is empty. No resources will be served unless a custom ResourceResolver is configured as an alternative to PathResourceResolver.`

Comment: @MuratAykanat I updated the answer to be more descriptive.  Given the error you describing it sounds like you might be adding Spring Content to an existing project.  If the above new answer doesnt resolve it for you then a stack trace would be very helpful.

Comment: @PaulWarren How i can configure in xml based application (spring 4) , i am facing same problem. Please help me to get rid out of this.

Comment: @Bylucky, unfortunately, Spring Content doesn't support XML config yet.  I would recommend that you convert to java config (as I believe XML config is considered deprecated) but if you really do need it then you can raise an issue on the GitHub repo.